# Deadlocks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, c#, deadlock

We're currently encountering a problem with out ASP.NET Application that results in deadlocks on the SQL Server database. A bit of background information I can provide is that we rely heavy on AJAX callbacks.

The problem occurs on a page with various "fields" that contain information about a resource. The user can click on each field to turn it into "edit mode" which allows the change of data. Basically what this does is open a transaction, save the item, update the html and close the transaction.

The user can change the data and then save the changes again with a transaction. We also have buttons that can be pressed to trigger scripts (C# dynamic code) which run a new transaction.

Below is a small transcript of two threads running in such a scenario and what they're doing.

*** Thread 1 ***

```
Step 1. SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL read committed 
Step 2. begin transaction 
Step 3. update Person set Name = 'Person1' where itemId  = 801 
Step 7. update Person set Name = 'Person3' where itemId  = 801 
Step x. commit transaction
```

*** Thread 2 ***

```
Step 4. SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL read committed 
Step 5. begin transaction 
Step 6. update Person set Name = 'Person2' where itemId  = 801 
Step x. commit transaction
```

After executing step 7 you will receive a deadlock.

```
> Transaction (Process ID 124) was deadlocked on lock resources with
> another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
> transaction.
```

We're currently investigating how deadlocks are working in SQL Server and how we can prevent them from our side, but any input/advice on this to do/check is welcome.

If additional information is required, I can add it as long as it's not violating our rules here at work.

Comment: Have you captured the deadlock graph? Not sure the example in your OP would cause a deadlock. `T1` would maintain an `X` lock on `itemId  = 801` following step 3 so would have thought `T2` would be blocked at step 6 and that `T1` would be fine at step 7 as it already has the required locks. What resource does T2 acquire that T1 needs?

Comment: One of our devs looked at the graphs, and we currently replaced the indexes on the tables with clustered indexes. Deadlocks seem to be gone for the moment.

Comment: I don't think this would be a true deadlock, just blocking.

Comment: It's definitly a deadlock, as the log clearly states that thread X has been aborted as victim of a deadlock on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to solve deadlocks depends entirely on your data requirements.

Are you content with only applying the last update to the data ?
In that case, don't use a transaction at all - this will happen automatically.

Does every user have to see the real updates being applied for only that user?
This is what you are currently attempting, including (ugh) keeping a transaction open while waiting on a **web page**, of all things.

I would start with investigating the actual need to do this very bad thing...

Regardless of the ultimate goal, explicit transactions should be used sparsely, wisely, and with good reason.